# RavenDB embedded with Raven Management Studio?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ravendb, embedded-database, ravendb-studio

Is it still possible to use the Raven Management Studio with embedded? I only find 10 year old Questions with guides that use Parameters/options that don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the Studio for your RavenDB server in the defined ServerUrl.

**Access the studio with:**

```
http://<yourServerURL>/studio/index.html
```

**You can set your embedded ServerUrl:**

See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.3/Csharp/server/embedded#other-serveroptions

```
EmbeddedServer.Instance.StartServer(new ServerOptions
{
    DataDirectory = "C:\\RavenData",
    ServerUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
});
```

Without the ServerOptions, the embedded RavenDB server will start with a default value of: 
 `127.0.0.1:{Random Port}.`

**You can get the embedded Server URL with:**

[https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.3/Csharp/server/embedded#get-server-url-and-process-id](https://%20%20%20%20https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.3/Csharp/server/embedded#get-server-url-and-process-id)